# Cambiar una clase dese javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen

Tengo un slider horizontal que tiene una foto al lado de la otra, una unica fila.

```
<div id="portfolio_horizontal_container" class="onecolumn">
```

Si yo cambio en mi documento `html` esa linea por la siguiente, y actualizo el navegador, ahora la galeria horizontal tiene 2 filas de fotos, respetando la misma distancia que habia entre cada imagen con respecto la clase anterior, ademas agrega la misma distancia entre las filas de imagenes

```
<div id="portfolio_horizontal_container" class="two-ver-columns">
```

Bueno, visto esto, yo quiero agregar unos botones y darles la funcionalidad para cambiar entre una vista y la otra, para ello hice este codigo:

```
  $("#verPrincipal").click(function() {
        $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").removeClass();
        $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").addClass("onecolumn");
    })

    $("#verCuadricula").click(function() {
        $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").removeClass();
        $("#portfolio_horizontal_container").addClass("two-ver-columns");
    })
```

> Lo que me sucede es que, cuando paso de la clase `onecolumn` (la que inicia cuando abre el sitio) a la clase `two-ver-columns`, es decir, cuando hago click en `verCuadricula`, las imagenes se ajustan mal. La distancia que tienen las imagenes a los costados esta bien, pero entre las de arriba y abajo ahora la distancia es cero.
>
> Adjunto imagenes para que se entienda mejor.

1) La vista secundaria funcionando mal

2) La vista inicial del sitio

3) La vista secundaria correctamente (Si cambio la clase desde el codigo y no de javascript)

[image: La vista inicial del sitio]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes de tener algun error de digitación yo creo o si lo hiciste con flexbox talvez al navegador lo renderiza diferente si de inicios tiene una clase, es decir, renderiza diferente dependiendo de los estilos aplicados a la clase, no estoy seguro de esto pero es una posibilidad, que tal si intentas hacer lo mismo pero en vez de usar jQuery usas classList, que es nativo de javascript?, no creo que vaya a haber mucha diferencia, pero si la hay, entonces es culpa de jQuery.

Comment: No, debe ser algun plugin ya que estoy usando un template ya desarrollado. Ahora adjunto cual fue la solucion.